# Install in-house application inside an application when the iPhone is in Single app mode

Tags: ios, ipa

My in-house application is hosted in my website. I'd like to download and install it inside my application. Here is my code:

```
  @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.webView.delegate = self

    let htmlFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "install", ofType: "html")
    let html = try? String(contentsOfFile: htmlFile!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    webView.loadHTMLString(html!, baseURL: nil)

  }
```

The link to ipa in install.html:

```
<div class="section hero">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="one-half column">
        <h5 class="">Enterprise In-House App distribution.</h6>
          <a class="button button-primary" href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://myweb.com.com/ipa/manifest.plist">Download Your App</a>
          </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Run the application and click the "Download Your App". It will prompt to install.

[image]

After click the **Install**, the application will be installed without problem. But when I set the device to Single App Mode or Guided Access Mode, the popup won't be shown.

I'm wondering:

1. How to show the popup in Single App Mode or Guided Access mode?
2. How to execute **itms-services** directly? Actually I want to know what happened behind **itms-services**.

Comment: Are you trying to Update the same app? Or downloading other app?

Comment: I think in Guided Access Mode, the system won't allow user to use other apps OR change system settings.

Comment: @Lal Krishna I think doesn't matter it's the same app or another application. But for my case, it's to update the same app. And I think some MDM apps can do this.

Comment: I don't think you can but give a try to bypass Apple. Interested, Keep us posted.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to use an MDM to do this?

Comment: The simplest answer to your question is the MDM we're using now sucks. It doesn't work for iOS 10 when the device is in Single Application.

Comment: Did you find the solution??